# Join two spheres with a cylinder in WPF 3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I want to draw a normal graph with some vertexes and edges in 3D WPF.
That means vertexes are going to be a Spheres and edges are going to be a Cylinders.

I want to draw some of the Spheres first and then connect those with Cylinders. I am able to draw the Spheres and Cylinders separately in a free space using the examples in Practical WPF Graph Programming text. I didn't get any help in joining those together.
How can this be done?

Comment: Situ, when you say "spears", do you mean like "round balls"? If so, the correct spelling is "spheres". Or do you mean a long, thick arrow (in which case "spears" is correct)?

Comment: Thanks andrew and potter you guys are right it's (Spheres). 
Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two spheres, connected by a cylinder, spinning in 3D space. The `Init` method takes two points, but I'm afraid you can only change the Z axis if you want the spheres to be connected properly.

The code is a bit of a mess, compiled from a number of sources, including your own sphere generation code that you posted in another question.

XAML with ViewPort:

```
<Window x:Class="wpfspin.Window1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Viewport3D Name="mainViewport" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="300">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera
                  LookDirection="0,0,-20"
                  UpDirection="0,1,0"
                  Position="0,0,100"
                  />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup x:Name="group3d">

                        <SpotLight Position="30,30,30" x:Name="mySpotLight" Color="Yellow"  InnerConeAngle="100" OuterConeAngle="1000" Range="100" />
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace wpfspin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init(new Point3D(0, 0, 30), new Point3D(0, 0, -30));
        }

        private Timer _timer;
        private readonly List<ModelVisual3D> _models = new List<ModelVisual3D>();
        private double _angle;


        public void Init(Point3D firstPoint, Point3D secondPoint)
        {
            var midPoint = firstPoint - secondPoint;

            _models.Add(CreateSphere(firstPoint, 10, 10, 10, Colors.AliceBlue ));
            _models.Add(CreateSphere(secondPoint, 10, 10, 10, Colors.AliceBlue));
            _models.Add(GetCylinder(GetSurfaceMaterial(Colors.Red), secondPoint, 2, midPoint.Z));

            _models.ForEach(x => mainViewport.Children.Add(x));
            _timer = new Timer(10);
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
        }


        void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<double>(Transform), 0.5d);
        }


        public MaterialGroup GetSurfaceMaterial(Color colour)
        {
            var materialGroup = new MaterialGroup();
            var emmMat = new EmissiveMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(colour));
            materialGroup.Children.Add(emmMat);
            materialGroup.Children.Add(new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(colour)));
            var specMat = new SpecularMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White), 30);
            materialGroup.Children.Add(specMat);
            return materialGroup;
        }


        public ModelVisual3D GetCube(MaterialGroup materialGroup, Point3D point, Size3D size)
        {
            var farPoint = new Point3D(point.X - (size.X / 2), point.Y - (size.Y / 2), point.Z - (size.Z / 2));
            var nearPoint = new Point3D(point.X + (size.X / 2), point.Y + (size.Y / 2), point.Z + (size.Z / 2));

            var cube = new Model3DGroup();
            var p0 = new Point3D(farPoint.X, farPoint.Y, farPoint.Z);
            var p1 = new Point3D(nearPoint.X, farPoint.Y, farPoint.Z);
            var p2 = new Point3D(nearPoint.X, farPoint.Y, nearPoint.Z);
            var p3 = new Point3D(farPoint.X, farPoint.Y, nearPoint.Z);
            var p4 = new Point3D(farPoint.X, nearPoint.Y, farPoint.Z);
            var p5 = new Point3D(nearPoint.X, nearPoint.Y, farPoint.Z);
            var p6 = new Point3D(nearPoint.X, nearPoint.Y, nearPoint.Z);
            var p7 = new Point3D(farPoint.X, nearPoint.Y, nearPoint.Z);
            //front side triangles
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p3, p2, p6));
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p3, p6, p7));
            //right side triangles
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p2, p1, p5));
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p2, p5, p6));
            //back side triangles
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p1, p0, p4));
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p1, p4, p5));
            //left side triangles
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p0, p3, p7));
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p0, p7, p4));
            //top side triangles
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p7, p6, p5));
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p7, p5, p4));
            //bottom side triangles
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p2, p3, p0));
            cube.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, p2, p0, p1));
            var model = new ModelVisual3D();
            model.Content = cube;
            return model;
        }


        private Model3DGroup CreateTriangleModel(MaterialGroup materialGroup, Triangle triangle)
        {
            return CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, triangle.P0, triangle.P1, triangle.P2);
        }


        private Model3DGroup CreateTriangleModel(Material material, Point3D p0, Point3D p1, Point3D p2)
        {
            var mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
            mesh.Positions.Add(p0);
            mesh.Positions.Add(p1);
            mesh.Positions.Add(p2);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
            var normal = CalculateNormal(p0, p1, p2);
            mesh.Normals.Add(normal);
            mesh.Normals.Add(normal);
            mesh.Normals.Add(normal);

            var model = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, material);

            var group = new Model3DGroup();
            group.Children.Add(model);
            return group;
        }


        private Vector3D CalculateNormal(Point3D p0, Point3D p1, Point3D p2)
        {
            var v0 = new Vector3D(p1.X - p0.X, p1.Y - p0.Y, p1.Z - p0.Z);
            var v1 = new Vector3D(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.Z - p1.Z);
            return Vector3D.CrossProduct(v0, v1);
        }


        void Transform(double adjustBy)
        {
            _angle += adjustBy;

            var rotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D { CenterX = 0, CenterZ = 0 };
            var axisAngleRotation3D = new AxisAngleRotation3D { Axis = new Vector3D(1, 1, 1), Angle = _angle };
            rotateTransform3D.Rotation = axisAngleRotation3D;
            var myTransform3DGroup = new Transform3DGroup();
            myTransform3DGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform3D);
            _models.ForEach(x => x.Transform = myTransform3DGroup);
        }


        public ModelVisual3D GetCylinder(MaterialGroup materialGroup, Point3D midPoint, double radius, double depth)
        {
            var cylinder = new Model3DGroup();
            var nearCircle = new CircleAssitor();
            var farCircle = new CircleAssitor();

            var twoPi = Math.PI * 2;
            var firstPass = true;

            double x;
            double y;

            var increment = 0.1d;
            for (double i = 0; i < twoPi + increment; i = i + increment)
            {
                x = (radius * Math.Cos(i));
                y = (-radius * Math.Sin(i));

                farCircle.CurrentTriangle.P0 = midPoint;
                farCircle.CurrentTriangle.P1 = farCircle.LastPoint;
                farCircle.CurrentTriangle.P2 = new Point3D(x + midPoint.X, y + midPoint.Y, midPoint.Z);

                nearCircle.CurrentTriangle = farCircle.CurrentTriangle.Clone(depth, true);

                if (!firstPass)
                {
                    cylinder.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, farCircle.CurrentTriangle));
                    cylinder.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, nearCircle.CurrentTriangle));

                    cylinder.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, farCircle.CurrentTriangle.P2, farCircle.CurrentTriangle.P1, nearCircle.CurrentTriangle.P2));
                    cylinder.Children.Add(CreateTriangleModel(materialGroup, nearCircle.CurrentTriangle.P2, nearCircle.CurrentTriangle.P1, farCircle.CurrentTriangle.P2));
                }
                else
                {
                    farCircle.FirstPoint = farCircle.CurrentTriangle.P1;
                    nearCircle.FirstPoint = nearCircle.CurrentTriangle.P1;
                    firstPass = false;
                }
                farCircle.LastPoint = farCircle.CurrentTriangle.P2;
                nearCircle.LastPoint = nearCircle.CurrentTriangle.P2;
            }
            var model = new ModelVisual3D { Content = cylinder };
            return model;
        }


        public ModelVisual3D CreateSphere(Point3D center, double radius, int u, int v, Color color)
        {
            Model3DGroup spear = new Model3DGroup();

            if (u < 2 || v < 2)
                return null;
            Point3D[,] pts = new Point3D[u, v];
            for (int i = 0; i < u; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < v; j++)
                {
                    pts[i, j] = GetPosition(radius,
                    i * 180 / (u - 1), j * 360 / (v - 1));
                    pts[i, j] += (Vector3D)center;
                }
            }

            Point3D[] p = new Point3D[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < u - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < v - 1; j++)
                {
                    p[0] = pts[i, j];
                    p[1] = pts[i + 1, j];
                    p[2] = pts[i + 1, j + 1];
                    p[3] = pts[i, j + 1];
                    spear.Children.Add(CreateTriangleFace(p[0], p[1], p[2], color));
                    spear.Children.Add(CreateTriangleFace(p[2], p[3], p[0], color));
                }
            }
            ModelVisual3D model = new ModelVisual3D();
            model.Content = spear;
            return model;
        }


        private Point3D GetPosition(double radius, double theta, double phi)
        {
            Point3D pt = new Point3D();
            double snt = Math.Sin(theta * Math.PI / 180);
            double cnt = Math.Cos(theta * Math.PI / 180);
            double snp = Math.Sin(phi * Math.PI / 180);
            double cnp = Math.Cos(phi * Math.PI / 180);
            pt.X = radius * snt * cnp;
            pt.Y = radius * cnt;
            pt.Z = -radius * snt * snp;
            return pt;
        }


        public Model3DGroup CreateTriangleFace(Point3D p0, Point3D p1, Point3D p2, Color color)
        {
            MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D(); mesh.Positions.Add(p0); mesh.Positions.Add(p1); mesh.Positions.Add(p2); mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0); mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1); mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);

            Vector3D normal = VectorHelper.CalcNormal(p0, p1, p2);
            mesh.Normals.Add(normal);
            mesh.Normals.Add(normal);
            mesh.Normals.Add(normal);

            Material material = new DiffuseMaterial(
                new SolidColorBrush(color));
            GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D(
                mesh, material);
            Model3DGroup group = new Model3DGroup();
            group.Children.Add(model);
            return group;
        }


        private class VectorHelper
        {
            public static Vector3D CalcNormal(Point3D p0, Point3D p1, Point3D p2)
            {
                Vector3D v0 = new Vector3D(p1.X - p0.X, p1.Y - p0.Y, p1.Z - p0.Z);
                Vector3D v1 = new Vector3D(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.Z - p1.Z);
                return Vector3D.CrossProduct(v0, v1);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CircleAssitor
    {
        public CircleAssitor()
        {
            CurrentTriangle = new Triangle();
        }

        public Point3D FirstPoint { get; set; }
        public Point3D LastPoint { get; set; }
        public Triangle CurrentTriangle { get; set; }
    }

    public class Triangle
    {
        public Point3D P0 { get; set; }
        public Point3D P1 { get; set; }
        public Point3D P2 { get; set; }

        public Triangle Clone(double z, bool switchP1andP2)
        {
            var newTriangle = new Triangle();
            newTriangle.P0 = GetPointAdjustedBy(this.P0, new Point3D(0, 0, z));

            var point1 = GetPointAdjustedBy(this.P1, new Point3D(0, 0, z));
            var point2 = GetPointAdjustedBy(this.P2, new Point3D(0, 0, z));

            if (!switchP1andP2)
            {
                newTriangle.P1 = point1;
                newTriangle.P2 = point2;
            }
            else
            {
                newTriangle.P1 = point2;
                newTriangle.P2 = point1;
            }
            return newTriangle;
        }

        private Point3D GetPointAdjustedBy(Point3D point, Point3D adjustBy)
        {
            var newPoint = new Point3D { X = point.X, Y = point.Y, Z = point.Z };
            newPoint.Offset(adjustBy.X, adjustBy.Y, adjustBy.Z);
            return newPoint;
        }
    }
}
```